# Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.ipojo [612]: Singleton conflict

Tags: osgi-bundle, aem

I get an error whenever I try to install the iPOJO bundle.

If I install it by itself or as a part of a content package I still get the error:

Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.ipojo [612]: Singleton conflict.

I am using iPOJO 1.11.2 and deploying it as a part of an AEM package.

Comment: What AEM Version are you using: 5.6.1 or 6
It seems that there is already a version of ipojo in the system bundle of OSGi...

Comment: We are using AEM version 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this package in the framework bundle, nonthelesse you could try the following and don't provide it with your package:
In your sling.properties File you have a key called "org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation". There you could try to add "org.apache.felix.ipojo.*" to the comma separated list.
Depending on the way AEM is started, the sling.properties file is located in a different folder. Best is to search for it an keep them in sync if you find more than one.

This is how you can make system packages that are hidden by default accessible in OSGi. I had to do this for org.w3c.* and for com.sun.jndi.*

Answer (score 0):

You most likely already have deployed a version of iPOJO and are trying to install a second version.

This is prohibited through the iPOJO manifest that contains: `Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.felix.ipojo;singleton:=true`. I didn't know this header until a few minutes ago, but this is [what the OSGi Core R4 spec says](http://www.osgi.org/download/r4v41/r4.core.pdf):

> **singleton** – Indicates that the bundle can only have a single version resolved. A value of true
>   indicates that the bundle is a singleton bundle. The default value is false. The Framework must resolve at most one bundle when multiple versions of a singleton bundle with the same symbolic name are installed. Singleton bundles do not affect the resolution of non-singleton bundles with the same symbolic name

Chose the version of iPOJO you want to use and remove the other.